# Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) polynomial multiplication in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to perform polynomial multiplication as explained in the [Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) draft.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function  y  =  multiply_x2( a )

  % a is a 1 x 8 binary vector 
  % y is a 1 x 8 binary vector 
  % t is a 1 x 8 binary vector corresponding to the "AES irreducible polynomial"

  y  =  [ a(2:8) 0 ];     % Multiply byte 'a' by 2 using "left shift" 
  t  =  [ 0 0 0 a(1) a(1) 0 a(1) a(1) ]; %  't' only becomes the "AES irreducible
                                         %  polynomial" if a(1) == 1, otherwise
                                         %  it becomes the "zero" byte array
  y  =  mod( y + t , 2 ) ;   % XOR operation on y and t, as described in AES.                
end
```

The code above is for

> "y = {02} . a"

(where "{}" denotes hexadecimal notation, whose binary representation can be interpreted as the presense of the respective power of x in a polynomial. For example, {02} corresponds to 00000010, which corresponds to the polynomial "x", {06} would correspond to "x<sup>2</sup>+x", etc, as per the AES docs)

I want to multiply `a` with `0e` , `09` , `0d`, and `0b`.
How will the code be for each of them? i.e. for:

> "y= ( {0e} . a )"
>   "y= ( {09} . a )"
>   "y= ( {0d} . a )"
>   "y= ( {02} . a )"

Comment: There are about half a dozen things I don't understand about this question. First of all, this notation `y= ( {02} . a )` is very strange to me. Normally in MATLAB, placing a value in curly braces `{02}` makes it a cell array. I don't think this is what you mean. Second, are you using `.` to mean `*` (multiplication)? If you're trying to multiply two byte values together, why are you putting them in binary? I'll leave it at that for now and maybe the other questions will get cleared up as we go.

Comment: @beaker `y= ( {02} . a )` is a notation which is in AES_fips-197. I am trying to implement AES in matlab. With `.` yes  I mean `*`  (multiplication). I am putting them in binary because, AES algorithm explains operations according to binary. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Can you tell us which part of the document you're trying to implement? I don't see your `t` value anywhere so I'm not sure what it does. Does this value change, or is it always `27` or `{1b}`? As far as multiplication, as Andy says in the comments below, there's not reason to do this in binary representation and make things hard on yourself; you can do the whole thing without any kind of decimal or hex to binary and back.

Comment: @beaker t is the AES polynomial, referenced as m(x) in the draft (bottom of page 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your interest. I am trying to implement AES in matlab. And I found the solution in the pages of http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf . Here is the function for the `y= ( {09} . a )` multiply operation ;

```
function  y  =  multiply_x9( a )

% Multiply byte A by 9 over finite field of AES
y2  =  multiply_x2( a ) ;
y4  =  multiply_x2( y2 ) ;
y8  =  multiply_x2( y4 ) ;

y  =  mod( y8 + a , 2 ) ;

end
```

And also for the any matrix multiplication `multiply_xx (a, b, p )` function can be used. Here is the function;

```
function  y  =  multiply_xx (a, b, p ) 


% Determine input lengths and check if they are equal
n  =  length( a ) ;
if  ( n ~= length(b) ) ,
    error( 'Operand input lengths not equal to each other!' ) ;
elseif  ( n ~= length(p) ) ,
    error( 'Operand input lengths not equal to modulus length!' ) ;
end


% Initialize result to zeros and start iteration row by row
y  =  zeros( 1 , n ) ;
for  i  =  1  :  n ,
    m  =  a(i) * b ;
    y  =  mod( y(1) * p  +  [ y(2:n) 0 ]  +  m , 2 ) ;
end


end
```

Comment: hopeTo: This was extremely relevant information to your question, which now suddenly makes sense what you're trying to achieve, making it an interesting question. I suggest you rephrase it accordingly to reflect what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your answer is very specific to {09} but it shows the general approach. I have provided a complete answer for multiplication in general below.

Comment: You don't need a `return` keyword in matlab, unless you want to return from the function at an unexpected point. The appropriate closing keyword is `end` but this can be omitted for syntactic convenience if there are no other subfunctions defined in the same file.

Comment: But if there are some other functions except the function ?

Comment: if you have more than one function in the same file then the top function is the principal function (and needs to have the same name as the file), and the remaining functions in the file are *subfunctions* (or *local functions*), and are only accessible by the principal function. And they should all have `end` keywords to make it clear where each function starts and ends. The `return` keyword is of no relevance though. It's only used to return early (look at the examples in my answer and you'll see what I mean). Also [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html)

Comment: OK. I understand the situation for the functions now. Thank you very much for your broad explanations.  And I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This was an interesting problem. Here is a general solution for multiplication as defined in the AES doc you linked. I use the name `xtime` for the {02} multiplication, and I implement "addition" (xadd) as an XOR operation (i.e. `!=`) directly, since this is easier.

**Helper functions:**

```
%% in file isByte.m
function Out = isByte (a)
  a = a(:).'; % ensure horizontal vector representation
  if all (a == 0 | a == 1) && length (a) == 8; Out = true; return; end
  Out = false;
end
```

```
%% in file byte2hex.m
function Out = byte2hex (a)
  a = a(:).'; % ensure horizontal vector
  assert (isByte (a), 'Input needs to be a valid "byte" array');
  Out = sum (a .* ([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] .^ [7:-1:0])); Out = dec2hex (Out);  
end
```

```
%% in file hex2byte.m
function Out = hex2byte (h)
  assert (isxdigit (h) && hex2dec (h) < 256, 'Input needs to be a valid hex number below FF');
  Out = dec2bin (hex2dec (h));  Out = sprintf ('%8s', Out); 
  Out = Out - 48             ;  Out(Out == -16) = 0; % convert spaces to zeros
end
```

**Polynomial functions:**

```
%% in file xadd.m
function Out = xadd (a, b)
  a = a(:).'; b = b(:).'; % ensure horizontal vector representations
  assert (isByte (a) && isByte (b), 'Inputs need to be valid "byte" arrays');
  Out = a != b;
end
```

```
%% in file xtime.m
function Out = xtime (a)
  a = a(:).'; % ensure horizontal vector
  assert (isByte (a), 'Input needs to be a valid "byte" array');
  Out = [a(2 : 8), 0]; % left shift
  if a(1) == 1
    Out = xadd (Out, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]);  % subtract (= add) the AES m(x) polynomial
  end  
end
```

```
% in file xmultiply.m
function Out = xmultiply (a, b)
  a = a(:)'; b = b(:)'; % ensure horizontal vector representations
  assert (isByte(a) && isByte(b), 'Inputs need to be valid "byte" arrays');

  Out = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  if a == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] || b == [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; return; end
  if b(8) == 1; Out = xadd (Out, a); end % yes this could be done recursively but, why bother.
  if b(7) == 1; Out = xadd (Out, xtime (a)); end
  if b(6) == 1; Out = xadd (Out, xtime (xtime (a))); end
  if b(5) == 1; Out = xadd (Out, xtime (xtime (xtime (a)))); end
  if b(4) == 1; Out = xadd (Out, xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (a))))); end
  if b(3) == 1; Out = xadd (Out, xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (a)))))); end
  if b(2) == 1; Out = xadd (Out, xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (a))))))); end
  if b(1) == 1; Out = xadd (Out, xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (xtime (a)))))))); end  
end
```

**Example use:** (same example as in the AES doc)

```
octave:1> a = hex2byte("57")
  a =
     0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1
octave:2> b = hex2byte("13")
  b =
     0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1
octave:3> c = xmultiply(a, b)
  c =
     1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
octave:4> byte2hex(c)
  ans = FE
```

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB/Octave, `conv` and `deconv` are respectively correspond to multiplication and (division/modulo) operations for polynomials.

```
function out = multiply(A, x)
    mult = mod(conv(A,x), 2); % poynomial multiplication
    [~, modulo] = deconv(mult, [1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1]); %modulo operation
    out = mod(modulo(end-7:end) , 2); %extract last 8 bits
end
```

For example to multiply `0x57` and `0x13`

```
a = [1 0 1 0 1 1 1]; %0x57
b = [1 0 0 1 1]; %0x13
result = multiply(a,b)

result = 
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
```

that is binary representation of `0xFE`